# What's the best way to pass an array from python to C?

Tags: python, c, arrays, cython

I wrote a `C` application which uses some `python` code, wrapped in `cython`, to simplify some stuffs.
What I want to do is to return an array from a `python` function, callable in `C`.

**main.c**

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("wrapper", PyInit_libwrapper);
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("wrapper");

char *names[] = get_names();

Py_Finalize();
```

**wrapper.pyx**

```
cdef public void get_names():
    names = []
    names.append('ABCD')
    names.append('1234')
    names.append('abcd')

    return names
    return names_size
```

Is it possible to return an array, of `chars*` in that case?
To handle the array in `C` I also need to have its size, but I can't pass an `int size` by reference.
What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720121/return-an-array-from-python-to-c

Comment: Your python construct is a list of strings.  What exactly would be the `c` equivalent?  Python strings are unicode.  And a list contains pointers/references to those strings, not the strings themselves.   Usually when working with Python and cython, `array` refers to a `numpy` `ndarray`, which is different from a Python list.